# Rmi Server client remote conection with downloading code localhost

Tags: java, interface, rmi, permission-denied

So lets begin... not a simple question at my point of view at least...
I have create an Rmi Server property works fine .

Inside to server i need to create a file if it rus for first time or overwrite it if it is already there. (1)

I have successfully created an rmi Client , i test the project works fine with the client class in the same project.

On my Rmi interface in some methods i need to pass Clients object as a parameter (2).

Here begins the problem . I need to run my Rmi Client multiple time but not using thread , I need to create another project that each one of them(client project), has the same code and run from there. When i run the Client from Servers project runs perfect, but When i run another distanced client it fails
giving me the common error for Security Mangager

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:584)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
    at Client.<init>(Client.java:69)
    at Client.main(Client.java:142)
C:\Users\blue-icon\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

So i googled and googled and saw that i need the security manager in order to give permission to a remote Client to download the Servers Code .So i add security Manager to server but because i use streams for my files(1) it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "Subscribe.txt" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:814)
    at RMIServer03.checkFile(RMIServer03.java:132)
    at RMIServer03.<init>(RMIServer03.java:46)
    at RMIServer03.main(RMIServer03.java:56)
```

(2) i cant compile my Server and interface on server project without an instance of clients Class because i need to pass it ass a parameter as i said
any help?

Answer (score 0):

You misread. You need the security manager at the client, not the server.